# Overloading operators (pointers)

Tags: c++, pointers

Is there an overloading operator for a pointer ? if there is can anyone mention how to write it ? I am new at this so any help would be appreciated
thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you traing to achieve?

Comment: You can overload the unary `*` and `->` operators, if that's what you mean.

Comment: You can only overload operators if at least one operand is of user-defined type.

Comment: Please edit your post with an example of what you would like to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `std::unique_ptr` and the `std::shared_ptr` standard definitions and `class` definitions.  They'll show you how you can use a `class` to completely mimic a pointer while implementing very interesting behavior under the hood.